# Bluetooth headphones don't show up in BLE scan

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using some JLab Bluetooth earbuds that the box says are Bluetooth 4.2 (OSX reported it as 4.1). This should qualify it as BLE (I think). I am unable to get them to show in any form of BLE scans. Please see below for the list of things I've tried.

- I have tried manually scanning in code and using BLE scanner applications.
- I have tried scanning before and after pairing.
- I have tried on iOS, Android, and Mac.

The native OS Bluetooth connection tools see it and connect as expected, so I don't believe there is anything wrong with the hardware.

My assumption at this point is that they are still "regular" Bluetooth and not BLE (even though they are 4.x).

To summarize, the questions are:

1. Why are the headphones not showing up in scans
2. Will all Bluetooth headphones act the same/are other people about to see Bluetooth headphones in BLE scans?

Comment: BT 4.2 (4.1) does not mean that it MUST support BLE. Its just a Bluetooth version. BLE is optional for BT 4.x devices.

Comment: @Mike is there a way to tell if a device is BLE? (other than just seeing if it shows up in a scan?)

Comment: Only by quering its properties. You can check it with BluetoothManager demo from Bluetooth Framework (https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm). When you discover devices it shows a device type (Classic/BLE/Mixed). Perform both scans: as for classic and as for BLE. If you run something like Linux you can try to get device props by hcitool (but I do not remember the command exactly cause use Linux not too often)

Comment: @MikePetrichenko I was unable to find a really quick/fast way to test this with the BluetoothFramework you linked (would have required writing code). In the interest of trying to be lazy/fast in testing this, I found a Mac app in the app store called BlueSee (https://apps.apple.com/us/app/bluesee-ble-debugger/id1336679524?mt=12) that allowed me to verify my headphones were indeed "Classic" bluetooth. If you will create an answer from this information, I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: There is BluetoothManager demo that allows to check device tpye, not writing code required. Any way, for me my comment does not look as full answer. Full answer must have more details about differences in Bluetooth versions. So it is OK as comment but is not OK as answer (at least for me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MikePetrichenko provided most of the info that led to me arriving at an answer in the comments to the question. I don't like leaving my questions unanswered so I am answering, but if @MikePetrichenko would like to create an answer I will accept his instead of mine.

To summarize, the headphones are not showing up in BLE scans because even though they are Bluetooth 4.1, that does not mean they are BLE devices. To verify this I used a software called BlueSee on the Mac app store ([link here](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/bluesee-ble-debugger/id1336679524?mt=12)). @MikePetrichenko also pointed [BluetoothManager demo](https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm) as a possible tool to investigate.

The answer to the second part is less known for me. I am not currently 100% sure, but I believe that some headphones will show up as BLE devices, it just depends on decisions made by the manufacturer and features they include.